# useState state variable not updating

Tags: reactjs

So i created some state variables using the useState method:

```js
    const [claim1,setclaim1]=useState("Pending");
    const [claim2,setclaim2]=useState("Pending");
    const [claim3,setclaim3]=useState("Denied");
    const [claim4,setclaim4]=useState("Pending");
```

I then insert these variables in my render method to display the status of each claim. My problem is when i try to update them, I use a button which has an onclick functionality that uses the setclaim1 to the appropriate status. The button looks like this

```js
<button onclick={()=> setclaim1('Approved')} type="approve" className="submitbutton" >
```

I also tried using useEffect after the onclick but this ends up updating the variable once the page renders even without me clicking the button. Any pointers in what the right way to go would be great

Full code :

```js
// JavaScript source code
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from './assets/logo.png';
import React, {useState} from'react';


const ClaimApproval = () => {

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const onclick = () => {
        navigate("/mainpageLM")
    }
    const [claim1,setclaim1]=useState("Pending");
    const [claim2,setclaim2]=useState("Pending");
    const [claim3,setclaim3]=useState("Denied");
    const [claim4,setclaim4]=useState("Pending");
   
    
    

    return (
        <>
            <div className="formpage">
                <a onClick={onclick}><img className="logoForm" src={logo}></img></a>
                <h1 className='form-title'>Manager Approval</h1>
                <form className="form" class='center' align='middle'>
                    <fieldset text-align='center'>
                        <table class='center'>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>File</th>
                                <th>Approve/Deny</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Amy Darwin</th>
                                <th>$12.75</th>
                                <th>{claim1}</th>
                                <th>Claim.pdf</th>
                                <th><button onclick={()=> setclaim1('Approved')} type="approve" className="submitbutton" >Approve</button> <button type="approve" className="submitbutton" >Deny</button></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>James Peters</th>
                                <th>$34.34</th>
                                <th>{claim2}</th>
                                <th>expense_claim.pdf</th>
                                <th><button type="approve" className="submitbutton" >Approve</button> <button type="approve" className="submitbutton" >Deny</button></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Arch Mathis</th>
                                <th>$45.32</th>
                                <th>{claim3}</th>
                                <th>claim12.pdf</th>
                                <th><button type="approve" className="submitbutton" >Approve</button> <button type="approve" className="submitbutton" >Deny</button></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mark Collins</th>
                                <th>$23.45</th>
                                <th>{claim4}</th>
                                <th>claim.pdf</th>
                                <th><button type="approve" className="submitbutton" >Approve</button> <button type="approve" className="submitbutton" >Deny</button></th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                    
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    )

}

export default ClaimApproval;
```

Comment: You are writing the event listener in the html way (`<button onclick=onclick={...} >`), while it should be `<button onClick={...}>`, as you did above in your code.

Comment: I suspect the `<form>` is by default reloading the page.  Can you confirm if this is happening?  If so then your button's should probably be `type="button"` so they're not submitting the form.

Comment: Also, `class=` should be `className=` (as you already do elsewhere), and `onclick=` should be `onClick=` (as you already do elsewhere).  Ultimately, this just looks like a series of typos.

Comment: @David it appears that you were right and the form is reloading the page and ive fixed the button type so it doesnt do that. but my onClick function still doesnt seem to work even after a capitalized the C

Comment: @codeouz: When the various typos are corrected, [it works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bose-3h6rp2?file=/src/App.js).  Can you provide a [mcve] where you've corrected the typos and console errors which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David i seem to have figured out the issue. Due to the css of the button that i have on my local machine, somehow the button wasnt being clicked properly? i dont entirely even understand what that means but when I remove the css for the button it works fine. Thank you for all your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

In React use onClick instead of onclick like this

```
<button onClick={()=> setclaim1('Approved')} className="submitbutton" >
```

Also use className instead of class.

Here is the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: also "approve" is not correct type for a button
see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: @Omer Cohen you're right, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo:
You props of button is not 'onclick' but **'onClick'**.

For the future, I recommend you to take a look at your console, you may be able to see this kind of errors clearly.